# Maintain cursor position in window when typing (Using vim on Windows and/or Linux)

Tags: vim

When typing text I don't like the way the cursor slowly descends towards the bottom of the screen. Instead I would prefer if the cursor stayed in the same place and the text above the cursor moved up. I know about the 'scrolloff' option but I don't like it as it messes up H, L, and M commands and the 'zz' command is too much hassle.

Anyone know how to achieve this behaviour in vim?

Comment: Welcome [iorrus](http://superuser.com/users/106284/iorrus) to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) Please read the [FAQs](http://superuser.com/faq) before posting questions. Please edit your question to include your operating system, and the program your typing into.

Comment: @wizlog: http://www.vim.org/

Comment: and the operating system on which its running?

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case. vim performs the same on almost all of them, with the exception of a few keystrokes which aren't needed here. There is plenty of information to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `'scrolloff'` option to a high number to keep the cursor in the middle of the display:

```
:set scrolloff=9999
```

To do this only in insert mode you will need to use `autocmd`:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * :set scrolloff=9999
:autocmd InsertLeave * :set scrolloff=0
```

If you have line wrapping turned off, you can do the same with the `'sidescrolloff'` option.

Place the command(s) in your ~/.vimrc (~/_vimrc for Windows) to make them permanent.

See:

```
:help 'scrolloff'
:help 'sidescrolloff'
:help autocmd.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As a cheap and cheesy way of doing it, you can use

```
:imap <CR> <ESC>zzo
```

to perform `zz` every time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Insert mode.