# Maintain cursor position in window when typing

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maintain cursor position in window when typing (Using vim on Windows and/or Linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/359878/maintain-cursor-position-in-window-when-typing-using-vim-on-windows-and-or-linu)

When typing text I don't like the way the cursor slowly descends towards the bottom of the screen. Instead I would prefer if the cursor stayed in the same place and the text *above* the cursor moved up. I know about the 'scrolloff' option and the 'zz' command.

Anyone know how to achieve this behaviour in vim?

Answer (score 1):

From `:help scrolloff`:
"If you set it to a very large value (999) the cursor line will always be in the middle of the window (except at the start or end of the file or when long lines wrap)."

Comment: Thanks for the comments Walter. My only problem is that with the scrolloff setting the H, L and M commands don't work properly as it is now impossible for the cursor to be anywhere but in the centre of the screen!